# FFMPEG: Can't set the frame/borders correctly

Tags: ffmpeg

Source frame:
[image]

```
ffmpeg -i /www/1.jpg -vframes 1 -lavfi '[0:v]scale=ih*16/9:594,boxblur=luma_radius=min(h\,w)/20:luma_power=1:chroma_radius=min(cw\,ch)/20:chroma_power=1[bg];[bg][0:v]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2,crop=1056:594' -vsync vfr /www/output.jpg
```

At the output I get:
[image]

Task.

- You need to bring the original frame to a height of 594, change the width in proportion.
- After the dimensions of the original frame are ready. You need a canvas, height 594, and width 1056. On the canvas, you need to place the original frame in the center, and apply a blurry image on the sides.

As I do not try, everything is crooked. So much time has passed, and there is no result.

What to do. The original frame may be narrower and higher, or you may not need to add a canvas at all. How to set up so that nothing is cut, not much stretched, it was beautiful? Help...

The width changes in the center of the frame, if the setvar parameter is specified. But the center image is still cropped in height, that is, it does not adapt to 594px

```
 -s 1056x594 -lavfi 'scale=ih*16/9:594,setsar=1,boxblur=luma_radius=min(h\,w)/20:chroma_radius=min(cw\,ch)/20[bg];[bg][0:v]overlay=(W-w)/2:0'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

`ffmpeg -i /www/1.jpg -lavfi '[0:v]scale=1056:594,boxblur=luma_radius=min(h\,w)/20:luma_power=1:chroma_radius=min(cw\,ch)/20:chroma_power=1[bg];[0:v]scale=-1:594[pic];[bg][pic]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2' /www/output.jpg`

First, the canvas with blur is created at an exact required size of 1056.594. Then the image is scaled to `-1:594` - `-1` here means scale width proportionally. The result of the 2nd scale is overlaid in the center of the first.

You have one image, so -vframes or -vsync is not required here.

Comment: `crop=1280:480:0:38`, how to be in cases when you want to crop the image. It is not necessary to add a canvas, because the width goes beyond the limits and in order not to lose quality, I usually set the coordinates through crop. I try to register crop but every time gives errors.

Comment: `ffmpeg -i /2335.mp4 -c:v libwebp -lavfi '[0:v]fps=1/50,scale=1056:594,boxblur=luma_radius=min(h\,w)/20:luma_power=1:chroma_radius=min(cw\,ch)/20:chroma_power=1[bg];[0:v]"+str(crop)+",scale=-1:594[pic];[bg][pic]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2' -vsync vfr /%01d.webp`

Comment: With the crop sorted out. But now how to execute the command to get frames every 50 seconds. How to register correctly`fps=1/50,`

Comment: `-lavfi "[0:v]fps=1/50,crop='+str(Width)+':'+str(Height)+':'+str(x)+':'+str(y)+',scale=1056:594,boxblur=luma_radius=min(h\,w)/20:luma_power=1:chroma_radius=min(cw\,ch)/20:chroma_power=1[bg];[0:v]fps=1/50,crop='+str(Width)+':'+str(Height)+':'+str(x)+':'+str(y)+',scale=-1:594[pic];[bg][pic]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2"`

Comment: Works if you prescribe twice, is it possible to prescribe once for both cases?

Comment: `-lavfi "[0:v]fps=1/50,crop='+str(Width)+':'+str(Height)+':'+str(x)+':'+str(y),split=2[v0][v1];[v0]scale=1056:594,boxblur=luma_radius=min(h\,w)/20:luma_power=1:chroma_radius=min(cw\,ch)/20:chroma_power=1[bg];[v1]scale=-1:594[pic];[bg][pic]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2"`